# Finding the expectation and variance of a stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let $X_0, \ldots$ be i.i.d. $\mathbb{P}\{X_i = -1\} = \mathbb{P}\{X_i = 1\} = 1 / 2$. Given $a, b \in \mathbb{R}, |b| < 1$, consider the stochastic process $W_k$ defined as
$$
W_0 = a X_0\\
W_k = b W_{k - 1} + X_k, \; k = 1, 2, \ldots
$$
Find $\mathbb{E}[W_K]$ and $\operatorname{Var}(W_k)$.

---

**My attempt:** First, note that $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = 0$, $\operatorname{Var}(X_i) = 1$, and $\mathbb{E}[X_i^2] = 1$ for all $i$. Now,

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[W_0] &= a \mathbb{E}[X_0] = 0\\
\mathbb{E}[W_1] &= b \mathbb{E}[W_0] + \mathbb{E}[X_1] = 0\\
\mathbb{E}[W_2] &= b \mathbb{E}[W_1] + \mathbb{E}[X_2] = 0\\
&\vdots\\
\mathbb{E}[W_k] &= 0
\end{align*}
$$
(which there shouldn't be many problems showing inductively).

For the variance, we have (because the expectation is $0$)
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}[W_0] &= \mathbb{E}[W_0^2] = a^2 \mathbb{E}[X_0^2] = a^2\\
\operatorname{Var}[W_1] &= \mathbb{E}[(b W_0 + X_1)^2] = b^2 \mathbb{E}[W_0^2] + 2 b \mathbb{E}[W_0 X_1] + \mathbb{E}[X_1^2] = b^2 a^2 + 1\\
\operatorname{Var}[W_2] &= \mathbb{E}[(b W_1 + X_2)^2] = b^2 \mathbb{E}[W_1^2] + 2 b \mathbb{E}[W_1 X_2] + \mathbb{E}[X_2^2] = b^4 a^2 + 2\\
&\vdots\\
\operatorname{Var}[W_k] &= \mathbb{E}[(b W_{k - 1} + X_k)^2] = b^2 \mathbb{E}[W_{k - 1}^2] + 2 b \mathbb{E}[W_{k - 1} X_k] + \mathbb{E}[X_k^2] = b^{2 k} a^2 + k\\
\end{align*}
$$

Am I correct? Note that I assume independence between $W_{k - 1}$ and $X_k$ (and I'm not sure if I *can* do that).

**EDIT:** Okay, I see a mistake. I believe

$$
\operatorname{Var}[W_2] = \mathbb{E}[(b W_1 + X_2)^2] = b^2 \color{red}{\mathbb{E}[W_1^2]} + 2 b \mathbb{E}[W_1 X_2] + \mathbb{E}[X_2^2] = b^4 a^2 + 2
$$

should in fact be

$$
\operatorname{Var}[W_2] = \mathbb{E}[(b W_1 + X_2)^2] = b^2 \mathbb{E}[W_1^2] + 2 b \mathbb{E}[W_1 X_2] + \mathbb{E}[X_2^2] = b^2 (b^2 a^2 + 1) + 1
$$

leading to a geometric sequence in the end. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write :
\begin{align*}
W_k&=bW_{k-1}+X_k=b\color{red}{(bW_{k-2}+X_{k-1})}+X_k\\
&=b^2W_{k-2}+bX_{k-1}+X_k\\
& \qquad\vdots\\
&=b^{k-1}W_{1}+b^{k-2}X_{2}+\cdots+X_k=b^{k-1}\color{red}{(bW_0+X_1)}+b^{k-2}X_{2}+\cdots+X_k\\
&=ab^{k}X_{0}+b^{k-1}X_{1}+b^{k-2}X_{2}+\cdots+X_k
\end{align*}

Now you don't have independence problem !

---

$$\mathbb{E}(W_k)=\sum_{j=1}^k 0=0$$
$$Var(W_k)=Var(ab^kX_0)+\sum_{j=1}^k Var(b^{k-j}X_j)=a^2(b^{2})^k+(b^{2})^{k-1}+(b^2)^{k-2}+\cdots+1$$